# Hash conditions in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As I know I can rewrite this active record query

```
Some.where("a = :a and b = :b", { :a => params[:a], :b => params[:b] })
```

this way:

```
Some.where(:a => params[:a], :b => params[:b])
```

Now I need to rewrite this query:

```
Some.where("a = :a and b > :b", { :a => params[:a], :b => params[:b] })
```

How can I get it ?

I can use range conditions:

```
Some.where(:a => params[:a], :b => params[:b]+1..100000)
```

But I can not be sure in the constant 100000.

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it as the second style? It seems that having a comparison array with 100000 items in it is going to be slower than the original version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see why you "need" to rewrite it. It works as-is, and there is no way to do it properly with hash-based conditions.

That said, if you aren't a fan of SQL making a mess in your Ruby, you could take a look at the excellent [Squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) which lets you rewrite things like

```
where("name LIKE :name AND salary < :salary", {:name => "A%", :salary => 50000})
```

as

```
where{(name =~ "A%") & (salary < 50000)}
```

which I think is pretty cool.